# Zoom in an image and show a div on hover

Tags: html, css

On an image hover, I want to zoom in the image and also display a div with the transparent background on it.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9q4mT/

Here's my code. In the following example, when I hover over the image in the `.image` class, I want to zoom it, and want to display the link with class `.mylink` in the center of the div.

I am able to zoom in on hover but when I add style for the .text, it does not zoom in the image anymore.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a class="mylink">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image img:hover {    
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
}

.text{
    position: absolute;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.text:hover{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);    
}

.text a{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;   
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.text:hover a{    
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/ , this is what you are looking for. This is not it, codrops have lots of other similar tutorials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your CSS:

- Adding `display:block` to your image
- Adding the initial `transform scale(1)` to your img
- Adjust the hover CSS rule to **#box:hover .image img**

**Code Example** : **http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/MYBbMG**

```
.image img {
   display:block;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
}

.image img {        
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

#box:hover .image img {    
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```